# Inserting information into internet explorer with a user form

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, userform

This may be reaching but I need to know if this is possible.

I want to use a userform to insert data into a website, hit enter and then rip the data from the page.

For example,

I want excel to open google, prompt me with a userform box that I can type something into, then submit the search. Then pull information from the new page that pops up and insert it into a excel spreadsheet.

Is this even possible?

I know how to do the basics of excel opening the page and pulling the data into excel, i just need help with the userform (if its possible)

Comment: If you're looking for a how-to for userforms, then practice that.  There are many tutorials on the subject.

I suggest getting your hands dirty as soon as you can.  Make a userform!  Write some code!  See what happens!

Comment: Is it possible to make a userform imput data into IE?

Comment: Anything's possible!  I did this in the past with Windows Powershell, but the VBA code looked funny:  the VBA code "wrote" a little file with the .bat extension, then it caused that file to be opened.  When that file opened, Powershell input the stuff I wanted into IE.

Comment: This is too broad at present. You want selenium basic if using chrome browser. And yes, you can achieve what your asking in principle. I would use an inputbox to solicit the required information or a userform in completed in advance.